# Javascript local storage user created element with unknown ID

Tags: javascript

So, I'm a complete beginner in Javascript and is now trying to do a project with lists, where the user can either use the existing lists or create their own lists (div, ul), and also the list items (li), and sort the the contents between all of these, delete list items and also save everything to local storage.

So far I've managed to figure out how to save the existing lists and their contents to local storage, because I know their ID, but I have no idea how to save the lists that the user creates. When a user creates a new list, it gets the same ID as the name of the list, from user input, and the only change made is the ID being lowercase and spaces are removed.

I've tried to read a lot about local storage, and also looked into creating some kind of loop or array to store all of the ID's of user created elements, but I don't really understand much of it at all...

**Link to project:** http://elinrein.se/hv/gpa130/listproject/projekt-m4-list.html

Here's my entire script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // jQuery UI function to sort list items
      $(function() {
    $( "ul" ).sortable({
          connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
        }).disableSelection();
      });

          function addlistitem() {

            li = document.getElementById("name").value;

            if (li != "") {
            document.getElementById("regular").innerHTML +=  "<li>"+"<strong>"+li+"</strong>"+"<img src='x.png' onclick='deletelielement(this);'></li>";
            }

            else {
            alert("You need to write in something to add it!");
            }

            document.getElementById("name").value = "";
            }


          function deletelielement(litag) {   
          litag.parentElement.remove();
          }

          // Skapa ny lista?
          function createBox() {

          // Undeclared variables to enable access from local storage
          listname = document.getElementById("listname").value;
          listnameid = listname.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '');


          if (listname != "") {

          var div = document.createElement("div");        
          var headline = document.createElement("h3");       
          var ul = document.createElement("ul");        
          headline.innerHTML = listname;
          div.appendChild(headline);
          div.appendChild(ul);                                    
          document.body.appendChild(div);                    
          div.setAttribute("id", "greybox");
          div.className = "narrow";
          ul.setAttribute("id", listnameid);
          ul.className = "connectedSortable";

          $( "ul" ).sortable({
          connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
          }).disableSelection();
          }

          else {
          alert("Your list needs a name!");
          }

          document.getElementById("listname").value = "";

          for (var i = 0; i < listnameid; i++) {
          allcustom = listnameid[i];
          }
          }

          function savelists() {

          localStorage['listul'] = document.getElementById('listul').innerHTML;
          localStorage['regular'] = document.getElementById('regular').innerHTML;

          }


          function loadlists() {

          document.getElementById('listul').innerHTML = localStorage['listul'] || '';
          document.getElementById('regular').innerHTML = localStorage['regular'] || '';
          }

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save unique lists like this:

```
localStorage['savelist'][listnameid] = document.getElementById(listnameid).innerHTML;
```

That way, you'll have an array of saved lists in `localStorage['savelist']` or `localStorage.savelist`. Make sure you first define `savelist` as an object: `localStorage.savelist = {};`.

So, if I create two lists: `myFirstList` and `theOtherOne`, they would be available as:

```
localStorage.savelist.myFirstList
localStorage.savelist.theOtherOne
```

or the array format:

```
localStorage.savelist['myFirstList']
localStorage.savelist['theOtherOne']
```

---

Note, I suggest you actually save lists as arrays of items, instead of using the full HTML markup to generate list data.

As we spoke in the comments, here's a super-simple bare-bones example of using JS objects to create lists and save them into the localStorage. `updateLists` function is used to generate the result HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/t4h9Ldto/ (couldn't create it here as a snippet because of sandbox restrictions)

And here is a slightly improved version which allows adding items to the default list, using the same approach: http://jsfiddle.net/t4h9Ldto/1/

This should be more than enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a little bit, with the whole array thing, but I still can't get it to work, because even if I manage to save the list the user created by using listnameid, and get it into the array, I don't know what name (and thus ID) the user will have on their particular list... I've uploaded the code I have now so you might understand the problem better...

http://elinrein.se/hv/gpa130/listproject/projekt-m4-list.html

Comment: Since it's in Swedish I might need to add that the first form field is to create a list item, and the second one below is to create the actual "custom list"... They should be in reversed order. Anyway, if you create a custom list and then three list items, and drag one item to each list, and hit "Spara" (Save), reload the page, and then hit "Ladda in" (Load from save) you'll see what I mean...

Comment: I see, that's what I tried to explain - add all custom lists into a separate object (`localStorage.savelist` in my answer). That way you'd be able to access all the created lists by iterating that object. Makes sense? Plus, you'd make your life much easier if you only stored the list structure instead of full HTML.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but I'm really really bad at this. I kind of get what you mean but I just don't know how to do it... I'm about to give up on this whole thing, even though I'm sure your answer will solve it. Is there any way you could fix it in my code so the custom list and it's contents gets saved? 

I'm sure I'll get it when I see it but since I'm still learning I don't even know what you mean by "iterating that object"... Loop? I'm just lost right now... I've gotten a lot of help even writing the code I have so far, and it's pretty bad...

Comment: Yeah, optimizing the full code would be the best. I'll write you a fiddle with some ideas and custom list saving, so you can work from there. I've noticed you have a lot of duplicate IDs, they should be unique.

Comment: An example would be amazing. I'm normally pretty good with HTML and CSS but I've edited this file so much, focusing on trying to understand javascript even the slightest, that every single row of code looks terrible right now. The ID's I'll definitely fix. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Now, here's a modified version of your code - I've only changed the custom list handling, I think it should be enough to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/c58ko2mf/

Comment: Again, I'm **strongly** suggesting to keep/build the full list object instead of generating the parameters from the HTML stuff.

Comment: Here's a bare-bone example of saving lists (doesn't support list items yet): http://jsfiddle.net/t4h9Ldto/

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! This looks great! I haven't had a chance to dig down into your changes but I just quickly tried clicking the buttons and it seems amazing. Only thing I noticed is that when you load the custom lists there are two lists added, but that can't be too hard to fix.

I'm new to this place as well so I don't know what buttons to click to give you cred (let me know), but I am very grateful!

Comment: You're welcome!! LocalStorage works per-domain, so chances are something old is still loading, so clean up the localStorage first. About the buttons on StackOverflow, there is the accept button (you did that, and that button is only available to the question asker) and there are upvote and downvote buttons (for helpful and not helpful answers). Check out the help section when you get a chance, it's... helpful. :)

Comment: So, I managed to get it all to work great now! Thank you again! The last thing I'm trying to do now, though it's not necessary, is to have the option to remove the custom list as well. I added a img element with the same onclick function as the list items have, and it works (the custom list gets deleted from the screen), but not from local storage and the array. So when you delete it, save and hit load it comes back. 

Is that very hard to do? I tried copying the savelist function and changing it but I can't get it to work... Really not necessary, but it would be fun to wrap it all up. Thanks!

Comment: Again, let the `updateLists` function take care of drawing lists, you just need to remove the list from the `customLists` object and call `updateLists` afterwards..